# fullCalendar click event not working after updating calendar header on ngAfterViewInit event

Tags: angular, angular6, fullcalendar, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I have implemented FullCalendar in angular app and bind some events in full calendar. I have requirement to update calendar events with new data on button click plus display Day1, Day2, Day3... in place of Mon, Tues, Wed... So I have successfully set Day1, Day2... in place of Mon, Tues... on `ngAfterViewInit()` event of angular. but calendar dates click event is not working after that, also it's not updating calendar events with new data

fullcalendar html code:

```
  <full-calendar #calendar defaultView="dayGridMonth" [header]="{
      left: 'title',
      right: 'prev,next today'
    }" [plugins]="calendarPlugins" [weekends]="calendarWeekends" [events]="eventswithcount"
(dateClick)="redirectToNext($event)" (dayRender)="dayRendered($event)" (eventClick)="redirectToNext($event)"
[showNonCurrentDates]="false" [defaultDate]="this.date" [fixedWeekCount]="false"></full-calendar>
```

fullcalendar ts code:

```
@ViewChild('calendar') calendarComponent: FullCalendarComponent = <FullCalendarComponent>{}; // the #calendar in the template

ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (!this.viewFlag)//for stp to show Day 1 in behalf of sunday
    {
        let calendarApi = this.calendarComponent.getApi();
        if (calendarApi != undefined) {
            calendarApi.el.innerHTML=calendarApi.el.innerHTML.replace('<span>Sun</span>','<span>Day 1</span>');
            calendarApi.el.innerHTML=calendarApi.el.innerHTML.replace('<span>Mon</span>','<span>Day 2</span>');
            calendarApi.el.innerHTML=calendarApi.el.innerHTML.replace('<span>Tue</span>','<span>Day 3</span>');
            calendarApi.el.innerHTML=calendarApi.el.innerHTML.replace('<span>Wed</span>','<span>Day 4</span>');
            calendarApi.el.innerHTML=calendarApi.el.innerHTML.replace('<span>Thu</span>','<span>Day 5</span>');
            calendarApi.el.innerHTML=calendarApi.el.innerHTML.replace('<span>Fri</span>','<span>Day 6</span>');
            calendarApi.el.innerHTML=calendarApi.el.innerHTML.replace('<span>Sat</span>','<span>Day 7</span>');
        }
    }
}

redirectToNext(event: any) {
    let eventDate = event.date != undefined ? event.date : event.event.start;
    let datestr = moment(eventDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    if (eventDate.getMonth() + 1 == this.date.split('-')[1]) {
        this.dateClick.emit(datestr);
    }    
}
```

What can be the issue?

Comment: Not sure there's enough code here for a reproducible example or not (I'm not an Angular user) but I would guess that you've replaced some elements to which fullCalendar had attached event handlers. And since there are no event handlers attached to the newly-added HTML, then no events will fire.

Comment: But if you want to control the text in the column headings (I assume that's what you're doing, although it's not 100% clear), then you could just use the built-in https://fullcalendar.io/docs/columnHeaderText option. Using that is less likely to mess up everything, than overwriting the calendar HTML directly.